# Polynomials with high probability resulting in primes

Tags: probability, polynomials, prime-numbers

Are there polynomial functions $p:\mathbb N\to\mathbb N$ which increase the probability of resulting in a prime value further than the increment from the polynomials $p_1(n)=n$ to $p_2(n)=2n+1$?

Comment: How about the polynomial of degree $0$, $p(n)=2$?

Comment: @BarryCipra: Nice! But of higher degree then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For $n$ from $0$ to $N$, $6n+1$ or $6n-1$ has about $3/2$ as many primes as $2n+1$.

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: @Lehs https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_number_theorem#Prime_number_theorem_for_arithmetic_progressions